# A simple calculator. I want t show an error message, after the user types a number other than 1-4. It is in a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, calculator

I want to show an error if the user types a number 5 which is not in the program. Please help me out with this. I also want to try these
**Show an error if the user types the number 1,2,3, or 4 again** 
**I also want to show an error if the user types any other things like a letter for example**

```
 def add(num1, num2):
        return num1 + num2
    def sub(num1, num2):
        return num1 - num2
    def mult(num1, num2):
        return num1 * num2
    def div(num1, num2):
        return num1 / num2
    print("""
    Choose Operation:
    1. Addition
    2. Subtraction
    3. Division
    4. Multiplication
            """
            )
    while True:
        sct = int(input("Enter 1,2,3, or 4"))
        number_a = int(input("Please enter first number"))
        number_b = int(input("Please enter second number"))
        if sct == 1:
            print(number_a, "+", number_b, "=", add(number_a, number_b))
        elif sct == 4:
            print(number_a, "X", number_b, "=", mult(number_a, number_b))
        elif sct == 3:
            print(number_a, "/", number_b, div(number_a, number_b))
        elif sct == 2:
            print(number_a, "-", number_b, sub(number_a, number_b))
        else:
            print("error")
```

Comment: Does this code not already do what you want? `else: print("error")` seems reasonable.

Comment: When I type 5, no error is shown and it starts the addition process all over again. The print("error") is not shown.

Comment: The indentation of the code in the post seemed off, I've tried to fix it. Can you please check that it matches what you are running on your computer?

Comment: Sorry, it is not working.

Comment: @mkrieger1, With OP's original code also(which is off), this is not reproducible. But it's generally not advised to touch the code area while helping to correct question.

Comment: @Austin  I guess it won't work.

Comment: it might be a good idea to read the sct as a string instead of number to ensure that your code accounts for any mistypes other than 1, 2, 3, or 4. You could string comparison to "1" "2" "3" "4" and then else.

Comment: @vvp4 I've restored the original version of the code, but this does not run *at all*. Please make sure that the code you are running is reproduced correctly in the question.

Comment: I see the indentation is off for your function and while loop,  all the functions are written inside def add, I hope that is not intended

Comment: I saw this in this website:https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/make-simple-calculator-using-python/

Comment: I just added the wile loop, to make it more functional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would go about it :

```
correct_choices = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
user_choice = 'wrong'
prompt = """
Choose Operation:
1. Addition
2. Subtraction
3. Division
4. Multiplication
: """
while user_choice not in correct_choices :
    user_choice = input (prompt)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just started learning Python. But I am having a difficult time understanding this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by error if they type 5 as it already does that, but here's what you could do for typing a number again:

Define a list at the start:

```
ns_done = []
```

Then, add to the list each time someone selects a number:

```py
sct = int(input("Enter 1,2,3, or 4"))
if ns_done contains sct:
    print("error 123")
    continue
```

Then, add the number to the list if not:

```py
ns_done.append(sct)
```